# How to play video in the Preview Pane in File Explorer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On my old PC (Win 7) if I clicked once on a .mov file in File Explorer and had the Preview Pane showing, then within the Preview Pane there would be controls for playing that video (play button, pause button, etc) directly within the Preview Pane.

On my new PC (Win 10) the Preview Pane shows a still frame image from the video but there are no controls for playing it.

How to fix?

I have tried Windows Registry edits to enable the preview pane under current user, and also under local machine. I have tried various settings in File Explorer settings. I have tried associating the file type with Windows Media Player and I have tried various other things I found as suggestions on the web.

The issue was raised with Microsoft ([here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/video-in-the-preview-pane/a78a1932-d9cb-41f4-bc54-ba4d84d2506a)) but that suggestion does not solve the issue.

I am very surprised there isn't easily findable information about fixing this bug.

Comment: This is not a bug. On the old Windows 7 computer you must have installed a product that allowed playing from the Preview. This was never available in the standard Windows release.

Comment: Try copying this key from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP4\shellex\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}` to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MOV\shellex\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}`

Comment: @harrymc - plenty of people have raised this as something that was functioning in Windows 7 but not Windows 10, and if it comes down to a simple software install, I have not found any article with a definitive solution - only hacks to the registry and similar (and none work).

Comment: @user1292580 - stoked - that actually fixed it. Thank you very much. If you want to put that into an answer to the question I will accept it. I did not have a shellex folder under the MOV location. Added that and copied the default key's value as you suggested, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying this key from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP4\shellex{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f} to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MOV\shellex{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f} and the values.

I renamed an mp4 as mov (as I have no mov to test as they are really old) and it no longer had a playable preview, but a still preview. Showing me the preview handler can read it. I compared the preview registry settings and that was the difference.

Comment: Love that this was reverse engineered, as much as I love that the problem is solved. I just don't understand how a standard install of Windows fails to provide this functionality when it's clearly supported. Thanks again.

Comment: `.mov` is an Apple video format not a PC video format.

Comment: whether Apple or PC, it's being created by a Nikon DSLR.